# Converting truth table to algebraic normal form

Tags: algorithms, boolean-algebra

> Is there any *efficient* algorithm to convert a given [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) of a Boolean function to its equivalent [algebraic normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_normal_form) (ANF)?

I have seen that [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) has one implementation ([official documentation](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/cryptography/sage/crypto/boolean_function.html)):

```
sage: from sage.crypto.boolean_function import BooleanFunction
sage: B = BooleanFunction("12fe342a")
sage: B.algebraic_normal_form()
x0*x1*x2*x3*x4 + x0*x1*x2 + x0*x1*x3*x4 + x0*x1*x3 + x0*x1*x4 + x0*x2*x3*x4 + x0*x2*x4 + x0*x3*x4 + x0*x3 + x0 + x1*x2*x4 + x1*x3 + x1*x4 + x2*x3*x4 + x2*x3 + x2*x4
```

But, nowhere I could find the algorithm.

It would be helpful if someone kindly explains with a suitable example.

**UPDATE** The answer can be found [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47957/generate-anf-from-sbox). It is copied below.

Comment: The sage source code is on line 479 here: https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/master/src/sage/crypto/boolean_function.pyx.

Comment: @pushpen.paul can you write up an answer for this and accept if you wish, instead of putting it in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Source](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52920/16588) (Credit goes to user [pico](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/52927/pico) of crypto.stackexchange)*

*From TRUTH TABLE to ANF*

First write [6, 4, 7, 8, 0, 5, 2, 10, 14, 3, 13, 1, 12, 15, 9, 11] in that way: the columns of matrix are those numbers in $\mathbb{F_2^4}$.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&1&1&0&1&1&1\\
1&0&1&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&1&0&1\\
1&1&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&1&0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&1&0&1&0&1&1&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then multiply it with Moebius transformation matrix :

$$
M_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1
\end{bmatrix}, 
M_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}, \cdots,
M_{2^k} = M_2 \otimes M_{2^{k-1}} = \begin{bmatrix}
M_{2^{k-1}}&M_{2^{k-1}}\\
0&M_{2^{k-1}}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So for $k=4$,
the matrix is: 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 \\
0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 \\
0 &0 &1 &1 &0 &0 &1 &1 &0 &0 &1 &1 &0 &0 &1 &1\\
0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &0 &0 &1 &1 &0 &0 &1 &1\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &0 &0 &1 &1\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &1 &1\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &1\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then you have this matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&1&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&1&0\\
1&1&0&0&1&1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0&1&0&1&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&1&1&0&1&0&1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Each row gives the coordinate function $S_1,S_2,S_3$and $S_4$ resp.
The entries of each row are the coefficients of $1, x_0, x_1, x_0x_1, x_2, x_0x_2, x_1x_2, x_0x_1x_2, x_3, x_0x_3, x_1x_3, x_0x_1x_3, x_2x_3, x_0x_2x_3, x_1x_2x_3, x_0x_1x_2x_3$.

*From ANF to TRUTH TABLE (TT)*

Exactly the inverse of operations. Note that $M_{2^k}^{-1}=M_{2^k}$ for any $k$.

---

i.e. [TT] * $[M]$ = [ANF] and [TT] = [ANF] * $[M]$.

---

Note: The arithmetics are taken modulo 2.

Answer (score 2):

The sage source code implies that algebraic normal form is the same as the Fourier expansion of the function (over the group $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$, where $n$ is the number of input bits). You can compute the Fourier transform using the well-known FFT algorithm(s).

Comment: FYI, SageMath has [Sbox](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/cryptography/sage/crypto/sbox.html) package to calculate ANF and others. I've posted the code in [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/84272/18298).